# Developing for MS Project 2010 with SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-project

I am trying to develop for Microsoft Project 2010 with the Project 2010 SDK but I have not found much documentation on the internet, is there anyone who has tested this kit before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Project Server 2010 Check this out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/projectserver/ee263909.aspx